# Download file from website directly into Linux directory - Python

Tags: python-3.x

If I manually click on button, the browser starts downloading a CSV file (2GB) onto my computer. But I want to automate this.

This is the link to download:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/bnx9-e6tj/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Issue; when I use either (requests or pandas) libraries it just hangs. I have no idea if it is being downloaded or not.

My goal is to:

1. Know if the file is being downloaded and
2. Have the CSV downloaded to a specified directory ie.
   ~/mydirectory

Can someone provide the code to do this?

Comment: How do you know it’s hanging, and not in the process of downloading?

Comment: I waited about 10 mins and it never finished. Plus if it was being downloaded, I don't know where it was being downloaded to, as I'm on a server with no downloads directory, unlike my desktop.

Comment: Also, I ran `locate *.csv` and nothing came up.

Comment: I voted to close this question because SO is not a code writing service. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```py
import requests


URL = "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/bnx9-e6tj/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"

response = requests.get(URL)
print('Download Complete')

open("/mydirectory/downloaded_file.csv", "wb").write(response.content)
```

Or you could do it this way and have a progress bar ...

```py
import wget

wget.download('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/bnx9-e6tj/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD')
```

The output will look like this:

```py
11% [........                                     ] 73728 / 633847
```